# react-native image is not loaded in iOS 14 upgrade

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

After upgrading the version of iOS 14, the React Native failed to build.
switched the XCode build settings to "Legacy Build Settings" and succeed to build.

But the new build doesn't load images and the original section of images are now white screen

```js
<Image
  source={require('./images/home.png')}
/>
```

System specs

```
Environment:
Xcode Version 12.0
Simulator: IPhone X - 2nd generation - 14.0
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.62.2"
```

Comment: Hi, please take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29215)  or [this one](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29279) on GitHub. It should be fixed in react native 0.63.2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a problem with react-native <= 0.63.1 and iOS 14

This issue is fixed and merged to react native latest version. But if you want to fix your project now or you are using under 0.63.2 versions, there is a solution. (Thanks to https://bityl.co/3ksz)

**FIRST SOLUTION : If you can update React Native**

Update react-native to v0.63.2 or superior

Its was fixed in this release : https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v0632

**SECOND SOLUTION : If you can't update React Native**

1. **OPEN THE FILE FROM :**

> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m

2. **EDIT SOURCE**

> From
>
> ```
> #pragma mark - CALayerDelegate
>
> - (void)displayLayer:(CALayer *)layer
> {
>   if (_currentFrame) {
>     layer.contentsScale = self.animatedImageScale;
>     layer.contents = (__bridge id)_currentFrame.CGImage;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> To
>
> ```
> #pragma mark - CALayerDelegate
>
> - (void)displayLayer:(CALayer *)layer
> {
>   if (_currentFrame) {
>     layer.contentsScale = self.animatedImageScale;
>     layer.contents = (__bridge id)_currentFrame.CGImage;
>   } else {
>     [super displayLayer:layer];
>   }
> }
> ```

3. **MAKE PATCH**

> `npx patch-package react-native`

4. **MAKE PATCH FILES TRACKED FOR GIT**

> `git add patches/*`

5. **ADD PACKAGE SCRIPT FOR AUTO APPLYING PATCHES**

> package.json
>
> ```
> "scripts": {
>   ...
>   "postinstall": "patch-package",
> }
> ```

It will patch from all patch files whenever you install packages.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue on React Native version `"0.63.0"`. When I update the Xcode to the version **12.0** *(12A7209)* and then the project is not built on Simulator iPhone 11 (iOS 14).

Solutions (these are not steps, every one of them could be a solution):

- Use Simulator with iOS earlier than version 14
- Use `Legacy Build Settings` in the setting of Xcode

**NOTE**: *The correct solution should come from apple or the React Native and the above solutions are temporary.*

Answer (score 1):

I have facing same issue on React native version 0.62.  When I update the Xcode version 12.0.1 Catalina  MacOs version 10.15.7 initially local and remote url not loading after that I added patch file in version 0.62 that time local and remote url image showing in my simulator but not working in TestFlight build and iPhone device iOS 14 and above. But not working in TestFlight build and App Store. After trying some solution issue is fixed when **I upgrade react-native version 0.62 to 0.63.4**. Without any patches. And  following changes in ios Podfile.

**# pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon" //commented**
**pod 'React-callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/callinvoker" //Add this line**

After adding pod file update pod and run and following command.

```
        1.     npm install --save react-native-fix-image.                      
        2.     npx react-native-fix-image
        3.    add pod install command in ios dierectory
```

After completing all steps application run in iOS 14 and above device support also run in TestFlight build and Appstore Build Save my Life. Good Luck !!

Answer (score 0):

**It can display the image after adding [super displayLayer:layer]; if _currentFrame is nil if I understand correctly, _currentFrame should be for animated image, so if it is still image, we can use the UIImage implementation to handle image rendering, not sure if it is a correct fix.**

> node_modules > react-native > Libraries > Images >
> RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m

```
if (_currentFrame) {
    layer.contentsScale = self.animatedImageScale;
    layer.contents = (__bridge id)_currentFrame.CGImage;
  } else {
    [super displayLayer:layer];
  }
```